# WPF MVVM Canvas UIElement has strange Binding if the ViewModels have identical position properties

Tags: wpf, mvvm, canvas, observablecollection, dispatchertimer

A view model binds to the wrong `UIElement` if it has the same properties of another view model in the collection.

I have a `Canvas` control that represents a matrix and this canvas is bound to a collection of rectangle view models. Each rectangle view models relates to a model which has a Move() method that sets the co-ordinates for the model which in turn tells the rectangle where to move on the matrix (x,y).

```
public class RectangleModel
{
    public void Move()
    {
        // Logic to find out where to move
        // sets x,y coordinates for the model
        this.Location.X = x;
        this.Location.Y = y
    }
}
```

The Canvas View Model has a DispatcherTimer which when executed loops through every rectangle view model in the ObservableCollection of the canvas and calls the MoveModel() method which in turn calls the Move method on the rectangle model it references.

```
public class CanvasViewModel
{
   private void MoveAllRectangles()
   {
       for(int i = 0; i < obsCol.Size; i++)
       {
           obsCol[i].MoveModel();
       }
}

public class RectangleViewModel
{
    private RectangleModel InstanceModel
    {
       get{ return this.instanceModel; }
       set{ this.instanceModel = value;}
    }

    public int XPos
    {
       get
       {
          return this.InstanceModel.Location.X;
       }
    }  

    public int YPos
    {
       get
       {
          return this.InstanceModel.Location.Y;
       }
    } 

    public void MoveModel()
    {
        this.InstanceModel.Move();
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(string.Empty);
    }
}
```

This works fine and every second all the rectangles on the canvas move to an adjacent tile on the matrix. That is until a rectangle moves to a tile already occupied by another rectangle (view model with same XPos, YPos properties), once this occurs both the rectangles get bound to the same view model (so it seems) and once the timer executes both rectangles move to the same location. So if I start with five rectangles on the canvas, eventually they will all end up combining and only 1 rectangle will be left moving around on the canvas.

Debugging the problem results in rectangles to move around correctly, if a rectangle ends up in another rectangles tile then the next time iteration the rectangle will simply move out of the tile and carry on correctly.

Any help would be very much appreciated.